# how to draw line graph with line animation from left to right using chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I am implementing the line graph using chartjs plugin. My line graph is drawn
from bottom to top when loading. I would like the lines animated from left to right. How can I change?

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the chart and override the starting values for the animation in the initialize override, like so

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function(data){
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        this.eachPoints(function(point, index){
            Chart.helpers.extend(point, {
                x: this.scale.calculateX(0),
                y: this.scale.calculateY(point.value)
            });
            point.save();
        }, this);       
    }
});
```

Then just use the extended chart, like so

```
...
new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/kLg5ntou/

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helped me. Now the line is drawn left to right as expected.