# Filling area between two lines - Chart.js v2

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, chart.js

I am trying to fill the area between two lines in a line chart using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). Like this: [image]

There is already an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34161616/chart-js-line-graphs-fill-area-above-line-as-opposed-to-below-and-to-the-right), that explains how to extend chartjs to do this.
But I know this feature is now native in V2 (from [this thread on the github issues page](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1754#issuecomment-167355980)), the problem is I just can't find documentation referring to this.

Is there a section about this in the doc? Anyone know how to use this feature?

Thanks!

Comment: In the thread you linked, it says that the area is filled to the 0 line. so if the line is positive, the area fills underneath it (till the 0 line) and if the line is negative, it fills the area above it (till the 0 line). You might need to the use the extending method to get what you want.

Comment: I was going with the extend suggestion, but if chartjs version 2 has a native way of doing this, it should be better, right?

Comment: Have you managed to replicate this in v2? Native or by extending?

Comment: @SebastianPopa Not yet, I'm tackling another issue for now, since this is not a priority for me. But I intend to find out how to do this natively. If I find out, I will give an update answering the question here. I ask you (or anyone else) to do the same :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small plugin that can do shading between any two dataset lines.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41733045/852977

Answer (score 27):

Make sure you import the 2.6.0 version:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Then follow the rules as described here: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/area.html

Below is an example, and how it looks:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My two lines with colour between them</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mychart" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
        <script>
            var ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d'); //get the context (canvas)

            var config = {              //configure the chart
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Min",
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(55, 173, 221,  0.6)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(55, 173, 221, 1.0)',
                        fill: false,  //no fill here
                        data: [5, 5, 3, 2]
                    },
                    {
                        label: "Max",
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(55, 173, 221, 0.6)',
                        borderColor: 'rgba(55, 173, 221, 1.0)',
                        fill: '-1', //fill until previous dataset
                        data: [8, 7, 6, 5]
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    spanGaps: false,
                    elements: {
                        line: {
                            tension: 0.000001
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        filler: {
                            propagate: false
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                autoSkip: false
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            };
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Can you post some content that shows how version 2.6.0 will help solve the problem? Currently you have added a link to the official docs, which would be useless if the docs are moved elsewhere.

Comment: Ofcourse, excuse me I thought it would be self-explanatory with the documentation.

Comment: I have added an example. Actually @NisargShah after reading the original question: the request is actually for the official documentation and where to find that, so the link to the official docs would be the answer ;-)

Comment: This should be noted as the correct answer since it works without the need of plugins.

Answer (score 5):

Setting **fill** property to **+1** of a dataset will set the backgroundColor from this line to the next line in dataset.

```
datasets: [{
        label: 'Systolic Guideline',
        data: [],
        fill: '+1',
        borderColor: '#FFC108',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,193,8,0.2)'
      },
      {
        label: 'Diastolic Guideline',
        data: [],
        fill: true,
        borderColor: '#FFC108',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
      }]
```

See this: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/area/line-datasets.html

Comment: Also note that Setting fill property to -1 of a dataset will set the backgroundColor from this line to the previous line in dataset.