# How do you set chart.js background color gradient dynamically?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, chart.js2

I am creating a React app and using chart.js to show historical bitcoin price data from https://www.coindesk.com/api

I want the background of the chart to be color coded depending on the data being displayed. If a particular point in the data is low the background should be red. If it is high, it should be green. Somewhere in the middle and it should be yellow.

I can get the screen to show the various colors but they don't line up with the points on the graph as expected.

[image: example chart]

The troughs should be red and the peaks should be green but they don't quite match up.

I have already looked at these two stack overflow posts but they don't quite have what I need.
[Chart.js and gradient background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067337/chart-js-and-gradient-background-color)
[Chart.js line chart set background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464750/chart-js-line-chart-set-background-color)

I have also done more research into HTML canvas to see if maybe I am getting the width wrong. I don't think so but that's still a possibility.

```
class PriceIndexChart extends Component {
  state = {
    labels: [],
    data: [],
  }

  async getPriceIndexData() {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=2019-05-11&end=2019-05-23');
    let data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPriceIndexData()
      .then(d => this.setState({
        labels: Object.keys(d.bpi),
        data: Object.values(d.bpi)     
      }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }


  getColorStopColors = () => {
    const colors = ['rgba(231, 76, 60, 1)', 'rgba(241, 196, 15, 1)', 'rgba(46, 204, 113, 1)'];
    const numArr = [...this.state.data];
    const sortArr = [...numArr].sort((a,b) => a - b);
    const breakPoint = Math.floor(numArr.length / 3);
    const firstThird = sortArr[breakPoint];
    const secondThird = sortArr[breakPoint * 2];
    const max = Math.max(...numArr);

    let output = [];

    for (let n of numArr) {
      switch (true) {
        case n <= firstThird:
          output.push(this.getRGBA(n, firstThird, colors[0]));
          break;
        case n <= secondThird:
          output.push(this.getRGBA(n, secondThird, colors[1]));
          break;
        case n > secondThird:
          output.push(this.getRGBA(n, max, colors[2]));
          break;
        default:
          console.log('something went wrong');
          break;
      }
    }
    return output;
  }

  getRGBA = (num, max, clr) => {
    return `rgba(${chroma(clr).alpha(num / max)._rgb.join(', ')})`;
  }

  getColorStopStops = () => {
    const length = this.state.data.length;
    let output = [];
    for (let i in this.state.data) {
      output.push(i / length);
    };
    return output;
  }

  setColorGradient = (canvas) => {
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    console.log(ctx);
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, width, 0);
    const grdntStops = this.getColorStopStops();
    const grdntColors = this.getColorStopColors();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
      gradient.addColorStop(grdntStops[i], grdntColors[i]);
    }
    // console.log(grdntStops, grdntColors);
    return gradient;
  }

  makeChart = canvas => {
    const chartData = {
      labels: this.state.labels,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'bitcoin price',
          data: this.state.data,
          backgroundColor: this.setColorGradient(canvas),
          pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(254, 202, 87, 1)',
          borderColor: 'rgba(10, 189, 227, .8)',
          borderWidth: 5,
          borderJoinStyle: 'round',
          lineTension: .2,
        },
      ]
    }
    return chart;
  }
```

Comment: Do you really want a horizontal gradient here? It seems like a vertical one would be better suited to this dataset.

Comment: Well I thought it would be cool. I just changed it to a much vertical gradient with hard stops and it looks pretty good too. Much simpler of course. This still doesn't answer the question of why I couldn't get the data to match up with the colors, which I'd still like to know.